# Sort an array, so that duplicate values always come last

Tags: arrays, sorting

I want to sort array

example: 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5

I need to be sorted like: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 1 3 3

Is this possible?

Objective-C, Swift , or Javascript

Answer (score 0):

### Algorithm overview

1. Sort the array `a` the usual way;
2. Thanks to sorting, duplicate values are now adjacent in `a`, which makes them easy to spot;
3. Create new array;
4. Iterate through sorted array, move *new* elements to beginning of new array and *already-seen* elements to end of new array.

### Algorithm in pseudo-code

**Code**

```c
function sortWithDuplicateLast(array a_unsorted)
{
    array a = sort(a_unsorted)
    array b = new array with same length as a
    int j = 0
    int k = length(b) - 1
    for (int i = 0; i < length(a); i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || a[i] != a[i - 1]) /* if a[i] is new value */
        {
            b[j] = a[i]        /* copy a[i] to beginning or array b */
            j++
        }
        else /* if a[i] == a[i-1], i.e., if a[i] is duplicate value */
        {
            b[k] = a[i]       /* copy a[i] to end of array b */
            k--
        }
    }

    /* optional pass: reverse the order of duplicates at the end of array */
    const int number_of_duplicates = length(b) - k
    const int first_duplicate_index = k + 1 
    for (j = 0; j < number_of_duplicates; j++)
    {
        swap elements (first_duplicate_index + j) and (length(b) - 1 - j) of array b
    }

    return b
}
```

**Indices illustration**

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
                    ^ i

b = [1, 2,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 2, 1, 1]
           ^ j               ^ k
```

**Results**

```
a_unsorted             = [4, 2, 5, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3]
a                      = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
b before optional pass = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1]
b                      = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```